# Array_map through a array of objects and grab properties

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a `var_dump($instagram->get_images());` that gives me the following output:

[image]

I want to use array_map to map through all the properties and use them inside a foreach loop later on.. but I'm running into some issues:

Here is the attempt that I have:

```
$mediaUrls = array_map(function($entry) {
    return [
        'media_url' => $entry['media_url'],
    ];
}, $instagram->get_images());
```

I'm getting back the following error:

[image]

Could someone assist me on properly array_mapping through the objects and then later be able to use `foreach ($MediaUrls as $media)` etc...

Comment: Please don't post images of code/errors. Instead, post the content of the images formatted in a code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is correct. You're using array map on an object. But the object does have a `->data` property that is an array. But the items in the array are objects, so you'll need to refer to their properties rather than using array syntax.

```
$images = $instagram->get_images();
$mediaUrls = array_map(function($entry) {
    return [
        'media_url' => $entry->media_url,
    ];
}, $images->data);
```

---

Couple of suggestions. You said, "I want to use array_map to map through all the properties and use them inside a foreach loop later on."

1. You can reiterate `$images->data` later on, so I don't really see the value of making another array just for that purpose

   ```
   foreach ($images->data as $imageData) {
       // do something with $imageData->media_url
   }
   ```

   This would be almost exactly the same as iterating the array you're making with array_map.

   ```
   foreach ($images->data as $imageData) {
       // do something with $imageData['media_url']
   }
   ```
2. If you want to get an array of just the urls, you can do it more simply with `array_column`.

   ```
   $images = $instagram->get_images();
   $mediaUrls = array_column($images->data, 'media_url');
   ```

   (This won't give you the same result. It will be an array of strings rather than an array of arrays.)

Comment: Worked like a charm - Thanks @Don't Panic